# indexed search 8.6: search in section of the website

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-indexed-search

In TYPO3 7.6 (indexed_search 7.6.0) it was possible to search in a section of the website:

plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.sections = rl1_43

This does not work any longer in TYPO3 8.6 (indexed_search 8.6)
There is no alternative described in the doumentation.

Has anybody an idea how to realize this?

Comment: First of all: Use the stable version (8.7) instead of a version which is still in development.

Answer (score 1):

For TYPO3 8.7 use this:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = rl1_43
```

Comment: But what is plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.rootPidList ment to be used for?

Comment: This restricts the search to page level 1 with page id 43.

Comment: @JKB In the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/master/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#rootpidlist) there is a notice about `rootPidList`.  _By “root-page” we mean a website root defined by a TypoScript Template!_. It can't be used for 'normal' pages.

Comment: @Ludwig: yes, but can‘t figure out its sense, as „sections“ does nearly the same...

Comment: @JKB: As you already said, nearly. I think that `rootPidList` is only needed in a multi domain installation. There it can be used to control from which domain (root line) it is allowed to get search results from. Sections are used by the site visitor to filter the results.

Comment: @Ludwig: That’s funny, in my case (multidomain) it was just vice versa ;)